# NSURLSessionDataTask Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to do simple thing with NSURLSessionDataTask to get some data from server. Previously I was using NSURLConnection to get that data, but wanted to move my code to NSURLSessionDataTask. So here the code

```
 NSString *_urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/integration/admin/token",BaseURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]];

[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *_sendingData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"username":@"demo", @"password":@"demo123"} options:0 error:NULL];

[_request setHTTPBody:_sendingData];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *_defaultConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:_defaultConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *_dataTask = [_session dataTaskWithRequest:_request completionHandler:^(NSData *_data, NSURLResponse *_response, NSError *_error)
                                   {
                                       if (_error)
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Error %@",[_error description]);
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"No Error %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                       }
                                   }];

[_dataTask resume];
[_session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
```

It works Perfectly, I get output also. But when I run same code in Instrument I get following leaks [Instrument Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKPzp.png)

Comment: Can you find exactly what is leaking?

Comment: chk the image I have attached

Comment: There are several small leaks in Foundation itself. In many cases you cannot eliminate everything that Instruments marks as a leak. The total leak here is less than 1k. It's conceivable that it's a bug in your code, but unless this code is called very often (thousands of times) and the leak occurs every call, there is little value chasing it.

Comment: Yeah.  It looks like you're doing things right here.  NSURLSession just does that.  I'm betting it is some cache object.  That said, you should generally keep the session around and reuse it.